# VScode theme debugger on apple silicon M1

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

I'm new to all this. I already install node v15.14.0 on my computer and I follow this tutorial to create vscode theme. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGzssFNtWXw

When I try to test the theme by press F5. There was a pop-up said that

> You don't have an extension for debugging 'JSON with Comments'. Should we find a 'JSON with Comments' extension in the Marketplace?

I already got launch.json file. Is there any extension I need to install to test the theme? Is it relate to apple M1 that I can't debug? and what debug environment is suitable for vscode theme testing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typescript or JavaScript file in your project? If yes then open that file and then press F5 to run. You won't get that error. And `Vscode extension development` is suitable for testing/running any vscode extension.

If you don't have an ts/js file, create a blank ts/js file and follow the above steps then you should be good :)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happing to me, turns out VScode will do it all for you as long as you **open the folder with the theme** directly. If you have a workspace open, close it, then open the folder.

VScode was trying to debug your theme as it would any other json files, which wont work. Once VScode recognises that you are working on an extension, the launch.json file should looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```